# SkyLink Webrtc Api file transfer between web and IOS using datachannel

Tags: webrtc, skylink

Trying to send binary and text files, works great between browser 2 browser, IOS device to IOS device but not web 2 IOS. On web app message says file sent, on IOS it times out and no data is received, read some where it cannot send binary data yet, may have to convert it to base64, but there is no function to send text, any suggestions will be appreciated, I really like the api, but really need this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the `sendBlobData()` method for the Web app end as according to their Web SDK docs [here](http://cdn.temasys.com.sg/skylink/skylinkjs/0.6.x/doc/classes/Skylink.html#method_sendBlobData). By default, the `sendBlobData()` method should be able to convert to Base64 strings when not supported by the other device.

There might be a number of changes that could have resolved the issue in the last month according to the release note. Are you using the latest versions of their SDKs? I suggest you open a [support ticket on their portal](http://support.temasys.com.sg/) if there are still issues when using their later versions of SDK.